# Question about the equivalent circuit of an induction motor

Tags: power, induction-motor

[image]

This is the given equivalent circuit for the above parameters (from the problem's solution):

[image]

The resistance is R<sub>2</sub>[(1-s)/s].

However, my textbook shows that the resistance is instead R<sub>2</sub>/s for the equivalent circuit of an induction motor:

[image]

What is the significance in the discrepancy between R<sub>2</sub>/s and R<sub>2</sub>[(1-s)/s]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your top circuit, R2 is also shown as a seperate component. In the bottom circuit, R2 is combined such that: -

$$R_2 + R_2\cdot\dfrac{1-s}{s} = \dfrac{R_2}{s}$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> What is the significance in the discrepancy between R2/s and
>   R2[(1-s)/s]?

R2/s = R2 + R2[(1-s)/s]

The power dissipated in R2/s is the total power developed in the rotor. The power in R2 is dissipated as heat in the rotor. The power in R2[(1-s)/s] is electrical power converted to mechanical power.

Breaking R2/s into two parts more clearly illustrates what happens to the power developed in the rotor.

Comment: I think you need to check your algebra.

Comment: Thank you @Andy aka